# Grouping with TRUE/FALSE in Tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a dataset with the following layout (random example):

```
set.seed(1)

data <- tibble(A = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 10, replace = T), B = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 10, replace = T), C = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 10, replace = T), value = sample(1:100, 10))
```

For each combination of A, B and C I want to calculate the mean(value). Ideally, I want a new tidy tibble with these combinations of A, B and C and the result (including A, AB, ABC, AC, etc - all possible combinations of A/B/C if).

Here, rows 1,3 and 4 are all ABC which would result in

ABC - mean(89, 79, 33)

For row 2,5
B,C - mean(44,84)

How would I go about this?

Comment: If you are using `sample`, please ise a set.seed, otherwise we won‘t get a constant data pbject to work with. Also please clarify what you mean with „combinations of A, B, C“. So please also show what would be your expected output.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to group rows together that have the same value for A,B and C and then calculate the mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to use dplyr: group_by the variables A, B, C, then summarise the mean of the values:

```
library(dplyr)
dat2<-dat%>%
  group_by(A,B,C)%>%
  summarise(Mean = mean(value))
```

Comment: You don‘t need the ungroup with summarize. It does the ungrouping automatically.

Comment: Did not know that, edited my answer to remove the ungroup, thanks @deschen